# Unfamiliar edge is coming out of my model. How can I fix it?

Tags: modeling

How do I fix this part of my model where the edge seems like it's coming out of my model? It can also appear in the rendering. I tried tweaking the vertex, it disappears only if I move the vertex in a noticeable amount.
Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can't see it correctly... is it an edge coming out or is it a triangular hole, like there is a triangular face missing? Or a triangular face with a incorrect normal?

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I just answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's the wireframe overlapping with one another. Here's another image of a close up showing what is happening. The blue color is the "correct"/ outside way of the face, and the red is the inside face.[image]

Comment: Hello :). It might be caused by the Bevel modifier not having enough space. Checking *Clamp Overlap* could help.

Comment: Hi. This is no regular forum, please edit your question instead. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour