# Model displays a non-existing outbound edge when outside edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, edges, error

I am modeling the hair of a 3D character, and I am getting something quite weird. When I exit edit mode, an "edge" appears out of nowhere from a vertex in my mesh. There is no overlap between that mesh and its neighboring meshes, like [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/188204/112572) would suggest.

[image: Edit mode]

[image: Solid mode]

This is displayed with both smooth and flat shading, and both in solid and viewport shading modes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there maybe a vertex that's hidden in _Edit Mode_? Have you tried to unhide it with _Alt + H_? Or do you have some modifiers on the object like a _Bevel Modifier_ for example?

Comment: It was that! Consider putting it in answer form so I can accept it

Comment: I just edited my comment for another idea, but glad I could help you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a hidden vertex. Go into *Edit Mode*, unhide it with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and delete it.